# Firefox adding margin/padding to layout

Tags: firefox, padding, margin

I have some padding and margin "errors" in firefox that I haven't figured out yet.
[This is the test page where the screw-ups are happening.](http://dermsurgscientific.com/site/umsite/index.html)

This is the code for the HTML/CSS for the black caption box:

```
        #caption{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        margin: -4px 0 0 0;
        width: 650px;
        height:68px;
        background-color: black;
    }
                    <div>
                        <div id="slider2">
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/urban.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/urban2.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="img/urban3.jpg" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div id="caption"></div>
                </div>
```

This is the schedule code too:

```
        #schedule{
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #ededed;
        padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;

    }
        #schedule h2{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
        }
        .away{
            color: red;
        }
        .gameline{
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        }


        .lineup > li{
            margin: 0 0 7px 0;
        }
        #date{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
            list-style:none;
            width: 70px;
            float:left;
            padding-right:30px;
            font-family: 'Esteban', serif;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;  
        }
            #date > .gameline{
                border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0);
            }
        #opponent{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
            font-family: 'Esteban', serif;
            font-family: Arial;
            list-style:none;
        }

                <div id="right">
                <div id="schedule">
                    <h2>2012 Schedule</h2>
                    <ul id="date" class="lineup">
                        <li>APR. 21</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>SEPT. 1</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>SEPT. 8</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>SEPT. 15</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>SEPT. 22</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">SEPT. 29</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>OCT. 6</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">OCT. 13</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>OCT. 20</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">OCT. 27</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>NOV. 3</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>NOV. 10</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">NOV. 17</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>NOV. 24</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul id="opponent" class="lineup">
                        <li>Scarlet & Gray Game</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Miami(Ohio)</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Central Florida</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>California</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>UAB</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">Michigan State</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Nebraska</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">Indiana</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Purdue</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">Penn State</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Illinois</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>BYE</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li class="away">Wisconsin</li>
                        <li class="gameline"></li>
                        <li>Michigan</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a  inside your LI (for the date) and style the label instead of trying to put two LIs side-by-side and getting them to match. Set a width and `float:left` for the label.

Comment: Good stuff, I recoded it and cut down on code and headaches.  Forgot about that label tag!

Comment: One more thing, firefox is still adding like an extra pixel or two of padding/margin space on that black caption box.  I'm thinking I need a reset or fix for that  Got a clue?

Comment: It was the line-height that needed it.  Right on Diodeus!